# How to handle "Don't ask me again" Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

So I'm using the Silverlight toolkit sample to help me build a CustomMessageBox for a Windows Phone 8 app that I'm building. When a user clicks on a certain button inside the app I want to tell the user that they first need to launch something else before this button will work.

So in the message box I'll explain this to the user, but I want to add a "Don't Show me this again" checkbox. The problem is that I'm not sure how to handle the "don't show me again" checkbox in the messageBox.Dissmissed event. The toolkit sample leaves this part out and I can't seem to find  information on the internet that is really clear enough for me.

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm new to coding and rely on Samples a lot to get me going.

```
messageBox.Dismissed += (s1, e1) =>
            {
                switch (e1.Result)
                {
                    case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:

                        // Do ask me again.

                        break;

                    case CustomMessageBoxResult.None:
                        if ((bool)checkbox.IsChecked)
                        {

                            // Do not ask me again.
                        }

                        else
                        {

                            // Ask again later.

                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                }
            };

        messageBox.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user selects not to prompt him again, you can save his choice in isolated storage settings like this..

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings settings = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

if(!settings.Contains("DontAskMeAgain"))
   settings.Add("DontAskMeAgain", "1");
else
   settings["DontAskMeAgain"] = "1";
```

And before you prompt user with your CustomMessageBox, first check for setting DontAskMeAgain

```
if(!(settings.Contains("DontAskMeAgain") && settings["DontAskMeAgain"]=="1"))
   //CustomMessageBox.show();
else
   //dont show
```

Comment: Thanks for resonding....

Does your first code sample go in the place where I have the //Don't ask again??

And also where would I place your second code entry, that checks if the settings "DontAskMeAgain" go?? Before the messageBox.Show(); ?

Comment: I played with it long enough to get it. I checked the IsolatedStorage Settings file in App.CS initialize for the "Don't ask again".

THANKS a bunch.